# what can i do to cause realloc to stop working?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Its for an assignment. doing the good old banking app. I am trying to create a dynamic array using malloc and realloc so it gives me 1 more space for every account created. its just a test so it isnt complete at all. 
When i run it, it asks me for first name, last name and age, which i input, then on the second pass it skips right over the first name and goes straight to second name. its as tho realloc is not working. i even commented out the realloc statement and the result is the same. I thought maybe because i am not inputting the full 15 characters allowed for in the char arrays, the compiler sees some memory left, figures it is not enough for 2 x 15 element arrays, but is for one plus a 3 element array for age. same result with an int scanf (commented out). But that doesnt explain why I can index [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwps6.png) if realloc didnt create one. Cant debug either, GDB keeps saying Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is 4, should be 2) eclipse.

```
struct account{
    char firstName[15];
    char lastName[15];
    char age[3];
};
void assign(struct account* test, int count){
    printf("enter first name \n");
    fgets(test->firstName, 15, stdin);
    printf("enter lastName\n");
    fgets(test->lastName, 15, stdin);
    printf("enter age\n");
    //scanf("%d", &test->age);
    fgets(test->age, 3, stdin);
}
int main(void){
    struct account * test = (struct account*)malloc(sizeof(struct account));
    int count = 0;

    assign(&test[count], count);
    count++;

    test = realloc(test, (sizeof(struct account) + count + 2));


    assign(&test[count], count);
    count++;


    printf("%s\n", test[0].firstName);
    printf("%s\n", test[0].lastName);
    printf("%s\n", test[0].age);
    printf("%s\n", test[1].firstName);
    printf("%s\n", test[1].lastName);
    printf("%s\n", test[1].age);
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

i posted a similar question earlier with an earlier draft, but it turns out it was not the parameters that was the problem

Comment: `fgets(test->age, 3, stdin);` Will only read 2 chars from stdin which, I believe, leaves the newline in the input buffer when you enter 2 chars (`"41"`). And that newline gets consumed on the next call to `fgets(test->firstName, 15, stdin);` which is why you get an empty string.

Comment: Your question title is strange. So `realloc` is working and you're asking what you can do so it _stops_ working??

Answer (score 0):

Looking at manual page of realloc:

> The  realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed
>   to
>          by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged in the range from
>          the start of the region up to the minimum of the old and new sizes.  If
>          the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not  be
>          initialized.   If  ptr  is  NULL,  then  the call is equivalent to mal‐
>          loc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr is
>          not  NULL,  then  the  call  is equivalent to free(ptr).  Unless ptr is
>          NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to  malloc(),  cal‐
>          loc(),  or realloc().  If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is
>          done.

It's clear that realloc expect bytes for second argument not an integer value.

This statement: `test = realloc(test, (sizeof(struct account) + count + 2));` is not logical because `count` is not precisely calculated byte value.
What you want to do is allocate more space, clearly. So you can do something like:  `test = realloc(test, sizeof(struct account) * 2);`

Also calling realloc again and again is bad like you do it on your code. You can set a bigger capacity like *20* let's say and have a structure like:

```
if(count == capacity){
    test = realloc(test, sizeof(struct account) * 2);
    capacity = capacity * 2;
}
else{
    ++count;
    /*keep adding*/
}
```